# log4j properties file not found into netbeans spring

Tags: java, netbeans, log4j

I am using netbeans, and log4j for logging , but getting `file not found log4j.properties` Please help to right place for log4j.properties file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Place your `log4j.properties`  file into Default Package:

```
  - Project Folder
     - Source Package
       - Default Package
```

Answer (score 0):

Put log4j.jar file into Libraries folder and import correct namespace.
After that keep log4j.properties into a specific namespace and import that.